# how change data type already registered in the database

Tags: java, postgresql, types, integer

I'm working now on a system that defines a PK (primary key) of the table as `int`, this PK has a sequence with a rule:

`"YearYearMonthMonth" + 6 numbers`.

ex: `2105000001`

But the year of "22" (2022) was not predicted, or, if I were to adjust this pattern of the sequence to the current year, it would give an error, as it exceeds the max value. of an int.

Doubt: the system is huge, in java, PostgreSQL database, what would be the pros and cons to switch to Long? Would it bring database performance impacts something like that? Would all IDs already saved in the bank as `int` automatically change to Long? Sorry, but I don't know the safest way to solve this.. thank you

Comment: Can't you create a test database and try to make the change there to test?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server Change Primary Key Data Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41549549/sql-server-change-primary-key-data-type)

Comment: The "safest" way is to use ALTER TABLE and change the column's type from `int` to `bigint` - it's the safest because there is no alternative.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much for your help @hfontanez, I just have a question (until today I made few changes to the DB so this is new for me), but the data that is already in the PK as int will be lost (if I don't copy it to a table temporary and just do the switch from int to long)?

Comment: Wow what a good idea @a_horse_with_no_name, I hadn't thought of BigInt, that way I wouldn't delete the data already registered in that table and PK, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the data type without losing any values using ALTER TABLE:

```
 alter table the_table
     alter the_column type bigint;
```

Note that this will lock the table and its content will be re-rewritten. So you will have to stop any application accessing that table.

You also need to alter the types of all columns *referencing* that table.

Comment: Oh perfect! It became clear to me now, the project is huge and in amount of data in the DB as well, do you know if this change from int to bigint has impacts on the DB performance, for example getting slower as Bigint is a larger value and would use more space in the BD or something?
sorry if the question is too silly..

Comment: @Raquelhe: in theory bigint might be a bit slower, but I doubt you will see any difference