How to change the data type of primary key using code first approach?
There was a legacy code base which used GUID as primary key and tables are already present in production and having 10-20 million records. Now, I wanted to change the primary key data type from GUID to int using code first approach for better indexing and less fragmentation.
Database is SQL Server.
Checked a lot of sites but didn't get the solution.
Just wanted to check if someone has already done it in the past. EF Core.

I'm really not sure what you are asking. code first? This is a database migration/update/change/whatever. Update the field based on your needs

Existing tables are created using ef-code first approach. Yes, I agree its a migration change but what steps need to be taken to update primary key data type from guid to int(auto-increment by 1) without losing any data.

I don't believe you can migrate a database from using guid PKs to int PKs in code. I think you will have to hand code your scripts which need to be well tested because you have to move any FKs over as well.

Database is Sql - Server. Have you done something similar in any project? If yes then how?

I suppose I would create a new identity column for the integer ids...and then begin the laborious task of making sure all the objects start using the new identity column and stop using the guid column. When its all working - you are done ?

That can be for new records which will be created newly. Need to take care of existing data which is already present in production and update their Id's also.

remove the primary key add a new identidy column with bigint

Yes I have done it - the question has been asked many times before, what has your research shown you? I mean I get this at the top of a search https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41549549/sql-server-change-primary-key-data-type

Need to take care of existing data which is already present in production and update their Id's also when you add the identity column it will create new ids for all the records in the table (and new records added to the table).

Remember, all FKs need to be converted over as well. A stop-gap solution is to use NewSequentialId() for auto-generated PKs (which the DB, not code, should be responsible for new PKs) This does not completely remove the problem of index fragmentation but significantly reduces it. Combined with regular index maintenance to trim down the index storage you can help keep index sizes under control.
Using UUIDs for PK can be useful in highly distributed data models where the cost on indexing is offset by the flexibility to have data originate and coagulate between different data systems.

You simply need to change the data type from Guid to int, add a migration, and update the database. However, since EF Core needs to recreate the identity column, the property name must also be changed. Since the column is called Id and also has this Key attribute, the Ids will be auto-incremented by 1.
From:
[Key]
public Guid PurchaseId { get; set; }

To:
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }

